# Add argument to postsharp [Cache] CacheKey

Tags: c#, postsharp

i've got simple method with no parameters:

```
[Cache]
private void Get()
{
   int id = 5;
   var c = GetCustomerService(id);
}
```

I would like to Cache this method for different "id"s. "id" isn't parameter of this method.
Is there any chance to call OnInvoke() using my id argument to calculate proper CacheKey??

thx4help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your `Cache` attribute is `MethodInterceptionAspect`. During interception your aspect's `OnInvoke` code is actually executed first and then it can continue with executing your original method. It seems that what you're asking about is the opposite - calling `OnInvoke` back from the original `Get` method. This is of course is not possible.

You can perform some refactoring by creating a new method with all the parameters that define the caching key. Then inside your `OnInvoke` method you can just use [MethodInterceptionArgs.Arguments](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/P_PostSharp_Aspects_MethodInterceptionArgs_Arguments) to build the caching key.

```
private T Get()
{
   int id = 5;
   return GetInternal(id);
}

[Cache]
private T GetInternal(int id)
{
   return GetCustomerService(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanation:) I'm gonna do that, the way you said :) Have a nice day!